# Google OAuth2 application. Remove self from user authenticated applications

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I know it may sound weird, but I would like my app to disconnect it self from the user.

Just like any google user may enter his settings and disconnect like described here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5052/unauthenticate-google-oauth-connections

I would like my app to do this by itself. I found no information on that in the API docs, maybe someone have done this already.

I can't believe it's not possible to achieve. There should be some resource to remove any connections.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's very hard to find, but documented in the google api documentation.

#### Google:

[https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke](http://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

> An application can programmatically revoke its own access. This type of revocation is important in instances where a user unsubscribes or removes an application, in which an API request to remove the permissions granted to the application should be a part of the removal process.
>
> To programmatically revoke a token, your application sends a request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke and includes the token as a parameter:

`curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}`

> The specified token can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, the refresh token is also revoked.
>
> If the revocation succeeds, the response's status code is 200. If an error occurs, the response's status code is 400 and the response also contains an error code.

#### Other Services:

- Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#revokelogin
- Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/oauth2/invalidate_token
- SE: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/application-de-authenticate
- Github: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#delete-an-authorization

Twitter: It's not possible to tell if you can revoke all permissions with `invalidate_token`. Other options aren't available.

All services implementing OAuth 2.0 **should** provide one **revoke** possibility. Typically, it follows the `google-pattern` `https://..../oauth2/revoke`

Comment: This is great, thank you for finding, would be glad to see if there is any possibility to do this with facebook, twitter, github and SE

Comment: Bounty reward is available after 7h.

Comment: @Vlakarados I've updated the answer - there are now links to the other services aswell.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer - current link for google documentation about Revoking a token with code samples